# Include 3 step php form to wordpress template

Tags: wordpress

Hello i have writen 3 step multipage form in php

Files in form:

- first step: start.php
- second step: form.php
- last step: payment.php

I wonder if there is a way to add this form in wordpress template to page.php file or something?

My form is similar to this https://www.formget.com/multi-page-form-php/

Answer (score 0):

You can include external files in your site by using the Get Template Part function

Here is the [function in the codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

You can use it to include any php file that you wish, see the naming convention at bottom of the codex page

Comment: dont know why but it not working for me... i tried on few's templates.

Answer (score 0):

So i make custom template files with something like this

```
<?php
   /*
   Template Name: OrderBM-1
   */

   get_header();

   include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/orderForm/start.php" );

   get_footer(); 
?>
```

Files that i include, i paste in theme directory "wp-content/templates/temp-name/orderForm"